# How do I have this audio and LED activate ONLY when a button is held using an Arduino?

Tags: arduino-mega, interrupt, button, code-review, audio

I have this code that I am using to play a sound effect where I used a program called wav2c to convert a .wav file to number values that I put into a header file that I use in the code to generate the sound. I currently have it programmed to play the audio upon uploading it to the Arduino with an LED being activated along with it and staying lit for just the duration of the sound effect. I am trying to program it so that the sound and LED only activate when I am pressing a button. I have the pin the button is plugged into already programmed in but I'm not sure how to have it control the audio and LED as stated above. I don't have much experience with programming or Arduino so any help is much appreciated! I am using an Arduino Mega 2560.

The code

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

#define SAMPLE_RATE 20000
#include "Test.h"

int ledPin = 2;
int speakerPin = 9; // Can be either 3 or 11, two PWM outputs connected to Timer 2
const byte pinSwitch1 = 3;
volatile uint16_t sample;
byte lastSample;


void stopPlayback()
{
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    // Disable playback per-sample interrupt.
    TIMSK1 &= ~_BV(OCIE1A);

    // Disable the per-sample timer completely.
    TCCR1B &= ~_BV(CS10);

    // Disable the PWM timer.
    TCCR2B &= ~_BV(CS10);

    digitalWrite(speakerPin, LOW);
}

// This is called at 8000 Hz to load the next sample.
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) {
    if (sample >= sounddata_length) {
        if (sample == sounddata_length + lastSample) {
            stopPlayback();
        }
        else {
            if(speakerPin==11){
                // Ramp down to zero to reduce the click at the end of playback.
                OCR2A = sounddata_length + lastSample - sample;
            } else {
                OCR2B = sounddata_length + lastSample - sample;                
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        if(speakerPin==11){
            OCR2A = pgm_read_byte(&sounddata_data[sample]);
        } else {
            OCR2B = pgm_read_byte(&sounddata_data[sample]);            
        }
    }

    ++sample;
}

void startPlayback()
{
    pinMode(speakerPin, OUTPUT);

    // Set up Timer 2 to do pulse width modulation on the speaker
    // pin.

    // Use internal clock (datasheet p.160)
    ASSR &= ~(_BV(EXCLK) | _BV(AS2));

    // Set fast PWM mode  (p.157)
    TCCR2A |= _BV(WGM21) | _BV(WGM20);
    TCCR2B &= ~_BV(WGM22);

    if(speakerPin==11){
        // Do non-inverting PWM on pin OC2A (p.155)
        // On the Arduino this is pin 11.
        TCCR2A = (TCCR2A | _BV(COM2A1)) & ~_BV(COM2A0);
        TCCR2A &= ~(_BV(COM2B1) | _BV(COM2B0));
        // No prescaler (p.158)
        TCCR2B = (TCCR2B & ~(_BV(CS12) | _BV(CS11))) | _BV(CS10);

        // Set initial pulse width to the first sample.
        OCR2A = pgm_read_byte(&sounddata_data[0]);
    } else {
        // Do non-inverting PWM on pin OC2B (p.155)
        // On the Arduino this is pin 3.
        TCCR2A = (TCCR2A | _BV(COM2B1)) & ~_BV(COM2B0);
        TCCR2A &= ~(_BV(COM2A1) | _BV(COM2A0));
        // No prescaler (p.158)
        TCCR2B = (TCCR2B & ~(_BV(CS12) | _BV(CS11))) | _BV(CS10);

        // Set initial pulse width to the first sample.
        OCR2B = pgm_read_byte(&sounddata_data[0]);
    }





    // Set up Timer 1 to send a sample every interrupt.

    cli();

    // Set CTC mode (Clear Timer on Compare Match) (p.133)
    // Have to set OCR1A *after*, otherwise it gets reset to 0!
    TCCR1B = (TCCR1B & ~_BV(WGM13)) | _BV(WGM12);
    TCCR1A = TCCR1A & ~(_BV(WGM11) | _BV(WGM10));

    // No prescaler (p.134)
    TCCR1B = (TCCR1B & ~(_BV(CS12) | _BV(CS11))) | _BV(CS10);

    // Set the compare register (OCR1A).
    // OCR1A is a 16-bit register, so we have to do this with
    // interrupts disabled to be safe.
    OCR1A = F_CPU / SAMPLE_RATE;    // 16e6 / 8000 = 2000

    // Enable interrupt when TCNT1 == OCR1A (p.136)
    TIMSK1 |= _BV(OCIE1A);

    lastSample = pgm_read_byte(&sounddata_data[sounddata_length-1]);
    sample = 0;
    sei();

}


void setup()
{
    pinMode( pinSwitch1, INPUT );
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    startPlayback();
}

void loop()
{
    while (true);
}
```

The header file referenced in the code with the numeric values to create the audio.

```cpp
#ifndef _HEADERFILE_H    // Put these two lines at the top of your file.
#define _HEADERFILE_H    // (Use a suitable name, usually based on the file name.)


const int sounddata_length=32000;
//const int sounddata_sampleRate=20000;

const unsigned char sounddata_data[] PROGMEM = {
  15,1,49,0,150,0,138,0,219,255,133,0,176,0,15,1,210,


//There are many lines of more numbers in between that I cut out to save space

};

#endif // _HEADERFILE_H    // Put this line at the end of your file.
```

Comment: remove `startPlayback()` from `setup()` ... place it in `loop()` so that it is called only when the switch is moved from `released` to `pressed` .... when the switch is moved from `pressed` to `released` then call `stopPlayback()`

Comment: I moved the 'startPlayback()' to setup() and added                                   //buttonState = digitalRead(pinSwitch1);
     //while (buttonState == LOW) {     
         //stopPlayback();  }  And the same for stopPlayback, but it doesn't seem to be working, any suggestions?

Comment: read my first comment carefully ... the changes you made are not same as what i suggested

Comment: ok, I will reread. The audio does not play when I changed the location of 'startPlayback()' and the button doesn't affect anything.

Comment: also looks like you added comments, not code

Comment: don't forget that `loop()` repeats many times per second .... any code that runs when the button is in the released state (or in pressed state) will run at each iteration of `loop()` .... you want your code to run only once when there is a `change` in switch state

Comment: your best course of action is to test `intermediate code` ... in `loop()`, call `startPlayback()`, pause for 5 seconds, call `stopPlayback()`, pause for 5 seconds .... that will tell you if you can start and stop playback from within loop()

Comment: note: there is no reason to have `while (true);` inside `loop()` if it is empty ... loop() is while(true); already